# Statistics Homework Help

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

Not sure how to tackle this question, can someone help me?
 A team of medical researchers carried out a study among swimmers to investigate a possible link between exposure to chlorinated swimming pool water and erosion of dental enamel. The researchers considered two groups of swimmers: those who regularly swim more than 6 hours per week and those who swim less than or equal to 6 hours per week. For each subject in the two groups they recorded the presence/absence of erosion of dental enamel. The counts of subjects with and without enamel erosion for the two groups are reported below:
swims less than or equal to 6 hours a week: 127 have no erosion, 17 have erosion
swims more than 6 hours a week: 118 have no erosion, 32 have erosion

Is there evidence to suggest that the incidence of enamel erosion is larger in the group of those who swim more than 6 hours per week than in the group of those who swim less than or equal to six hours per week? Use the p-value to decide taking α = 0.05.

any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: For self study questions you best gain from the question if you explain what you understand about the question first. This will help readers understand what assistance to offer. What are your first thoughts on the question?

Answer (score 2):

Try to write the four numbers provided up in a 2x2 table. You have probably learned how to test for associations between two binary variables based on a 2x2 table.

Comment: That's definitely the way to go. Chi-square tests can be used to "accept"/reject the null hypothesis "variables are independent from each other"